# Error TS2345: Argument of type 'ListThingPrincipalsCommand' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: typescript, sdk

I have the following code in Typescript for a AWS SDK V3, `ListThingPrincipalsCommand`. Based on the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/iot/command/ListThingPrincipalsCommand/) the only mandatory parameter is the `thingName`.

This is my code:

```
const thingName = "myThingName"

const inputtp = {
      thingName: thingName
    }
    const command = new ListThingPrincipalsCommand(inputtp);
    const principalResponse = await clientIoT.send(command);
```

When I run `pnpm run build` I am getting the following TS error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'ListThingPrincipalsCommand' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Command<ServiceInputTypes, ListThingPrincipalsCommandInput, ServiceOutputTypes, ServiceOutputTypes, SmithyResolvedConfiguration<...>>'.
  The types of 'middlewareStack.concat' are incompatible between these types.
    Type '<InputType extends ListThingPrincipalsCommandInput, OutputType extends ListThingPrincipalsCommandOutput>(from: MiddlewareStack<InputType, OutputType>) => MiddlewareStack<...>' is not assignable to type '<InputType extends ListThingPrincipalsCommandInput, OutputType extends ServiceOutputTypes>(from: MiddlewareStack<InputType, OutputType>) => MiddlewareStack<...>'.
      Types of parameters 'from' and 'from' are incompatible.
        Type 'MiddlewareStack<InputType, OutputType>' is not assignable to type 'MiddlewareStack<InputType, ListThingPrincipalsCommandOutput>'.
          Types of property 'addRelativeTo' are incompatible.
            Type '(middleware: MiddlewareType<InputType, OutputType>, options: RelativeMiddlewareOptions) => void' is not assignable to type '(middleware: MiddlewareType<InputType, ListThingPrincipalsCommandOutput>, options: RelativeMiddlewareOptions) => void'.
              Types of parameters 'middleware' and 'middleware' are incompatible.
                Type 'MiddlewareType<InputType, ListThingPrincipalsCommandOutput>' is not assignable to type 'MiddlewareType<InputType, OutputType>'.
                  Type 'InitializeMiddleware<InputType, ListThingPrincipalsCommandOutput>' is not assignable to type 'MiddlewareType<InputType, OutputType>'.
                    Type 'InitializeMiddleware<InputType, ListThingPrincipalsCommandOutput>' is not assignable to type 'InitializeMiddleware<InputType, OutputType>'.
                      Call signature return types 'InitializeHandler<InputType, ListThingPrincipalsCommandOutput>' and 'InitializeHandler<InputType, OutputType>' are incompatible.
                        Type 'Promise<InitializeHandlerOutput<ListThingPrincipalsCommandOutput>>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<InitializeHandlerOutput<OutputType>>'.
                          Type 'InitializeHandlerOutput<ListThingPrincipalsCommandOutput>' is not assignable to type 'InitializeHandlerOutput<OutputType>'.
                            Types of property 'output' are incompatible.
                              Type 'ListThingPrincipalsCommandOutput' is not assignable to type 'OutputType'.
                                'ListThingPrincipalsCommandOutput' is assignable to the constraint of type 'OutputType', but 'OutputType' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'ServiceOutputTypes'.

383     const principalResponse = await clientIoT.send(command);
                                                       ~~~~~~~
```

Any idea what I am missing?

I am expecting not to have that TS error